# XSL-FO with 3d objects models

Tags: adobe, apache-fop

I want to generated a pdf using XSL-FO file. Adobe now has the capability to embed 3d objects inside PDF documents. 
http://blogs.adobe.com/tcs/2011/01/framemaker/interactive-3d-models-in-documents.html

Now I just want to creat a PDF file from FOP library which supports to embed 3d object. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not implemented, yet (2013-11-06). Consider implementing support for it yourself and submitting a patch to the Apache FOP project.